# What are compressed files within \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\?

Tags: installation

Does anyone know what are these zip files? Is it safe to delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are thumbnails dispayed in Sitecore backend.

Do not delete them.

First time Sitecore needs any thumbnail, it extractss one of those files and gets the proper thumbnail with requested size.

E.g. when you open Content Editor and select `Home` item:

[image]

you can see that icon it uses is

[image]

You can extract `Network.zip` from that folder you mentioned and in `16x16` folder (size of the file) you will find `home.png` icon which is displayed in Content Editor:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why they put them into zip files instead of standard folders?

Comment: I have no idea. It's like that from ages...